# Force resizing while using .text (jQuery)?

Tags: css

I'm adding the text Like with jQuery. This gives 20px of width to the elements that contain that text (they have width: auto). If you click the `a.gdt-starrating` link the text Like changes to Liked which now has 25px (due to the extra letter 'd'). But the elements still having 20px. So the text overflows the elements containing it.

```
$j(".gdup a.gdt-starrating").text("Like");
$j(".gdup div.gdt-starrating").text("Liked");
$j("a.gdt-starrating").live("click", function() {
    $j(".gdup div.gdt-starrating").text("Liked");
});
```

[image]

Here is a live example:

http://www.taiwantalk.org/topic/asdasdasdasdasdgg/

If you click the Like link you will see the issue.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What browser are you using? Shows as 25px wide for me in Chrome....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is this css rule

```
.gdt-size-20.gdthumb, .gdt-size-20.gdthumb a, .gdt-size-20.gdthumb div {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

in http://www.taiwantalk.org/wp-content/plugins/gd-star-rating/css/gdsr.css.php